# NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "1" NÃO CONSIGO CONVERTER STRING EM INTEGER

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, int

tenho uma String = "1" e não consigo converte-la em int, acho que pode ter algo haver com o modo como ela foi construida, a classe que lê o arquivo TXT da web e salva no banco está abaixo:

```
public class Downloader {

public Downloader() {
}

public ArrayList<String> baixarTxt(URL url, String fileName) throws IOException {
    StringBuffer datax = new StringBuffer();

    InputStream is = url.openStream();
    //InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, "windows-1250");
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

    String readString = br.readLine();
    ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    while(readString != null){
        datax.append(readString);
        arrayList.add(readString);
        readString = br.readLine();
    }

    isr.close();
    return arrayList;
}

public void salvarNoBanco(ArrayList<String> list, Context context){
    VendedorDB venDB = new VendedorDB(context);
    venDB.recriarTblVendedor();
    for(int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++){
        String linha = list.get(i);
        String[] dadosLinha = linha.split(";");

        Vendedor v = new Vendedor();
        v.setId(Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[0])); //#### <- O ERRO OCORRE AQUI
        v.setNome(dadosLinha[1]);
        v.setSenha(dadosLinha[2]);
        v.setMeta(Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[3]));
        v.setVlrAtual(Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[4]));

        venDB.inserir(v);
    }
}
```

}

A Mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
04-03 20:47:32.102 7800-7800/com.example.w190227 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.w190227, PID: 7800
java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: "﻿1"
    at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
    at java.lang.Integer.parse(Integer.java:374)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:365)
    at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
    at com.example.w190227.util.db.Downloader.salvarNoBanco(Downloader.java:61)
    at com.example.w190227.fragment.HomeFragment$DownloaderAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:148)
    at com.example.w190227.fragment.HomeFragment$DownloaderAsyncTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.java:126)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:632)
    at android.os.AsyncTask.access$600(AsyncTask.java:177)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:645)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

O método baixarTxt() é chamado no doInBackground() de um AsyncTask e o salvarNoBanco() é chamado no onPostExecute(), segue o código abaixo:

```
public class DownloaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Void, ArrayList<String>> {

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<String> doInBackground(URL... urls) {
        ArrayList<String> result;
        try {
            Downloader download = new Downloader();
            URL url = urls[0];
            result = download.baixarTxt(url, "grupos");
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("LOG", "ERRO: "+e);
            result = new ArrayList<>();
            result.add("ERRO no arraylist");
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<String> s) {
        Log.d("LOG", "Baixou: "+s);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Baixou: "+s.get(1), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Downloader download = new Downloader();
        download.salvarNoBanco(s, getActivity());
    }
}
```

E o arquivo de texto que é baixado da web está abaixo:

```
1;pablo;wt2009;10000;10000
2;waltair;wt2009;12000;12000
3;bruno;wt2009;5000;5000
```

Comment: O dadosLinha[0] , como string tá te retornando o que?

Comment: está retornando "1" sem nenhum caractere especial antes nem depois

Comment: Tenta usar minha resposta, se não funcionar avisa, e se funcionar avisa também rs

Comment: entretanto quando eu baixei o arquivo com o InputStreamReader com charset "windows-1250" aparecia um simbolo estranho antes do 1 mas baixando com UTF-8 o simbolo sumiu. Acredito ser algo do charset pois foi eu mesmo que digitei esse arquivo TXT no bloco de notas e com certeza não digitei nada antes do 1 porém algo me diz que pode ser esse caractere oculto o causador do problema.

Comment: Qualquer coisa dá uma olhada [Regex - Unicode](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como é um txt, provavelmente está recebendo algum caractere "non-printable". Tente o seguinte:

```
Integer.parseInt(dadosLinha[0].replaceAll("\\p{C}", ""));
```

Assim irá remover esses caracteres que são "non-pritable"

Comment: Barbaridade, xirú, eu pagaria um churrasco pra ti se tivesse dinheiro hahahahahahahahaha

Comment: resolveu mesmo, só substitui o "?" por ""

Comment: expressões regulares me dão um nó na cabeça XD

Comment: Já quebrei a cabeça com isso também haha